# Asp.net autopostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

Is there a way to add items to a dropdownlist (or any other control with lists) and when SelectedIndexChange happens, it doesn't keep adding all the items everytime that event happens?
I suppose one way would be to clear the list before the add code but is there another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are adding items to the list on `Page_Load` event. If you are doing that, in that case when ever `SelectedIndexChanged` occurs it will add the items again. You can check if its a PostBack don't add items.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) // First time only 
 {
  //Add items to list
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Check for `Page.ISPostBack` on Page_Load event.

```
if (!page.IsPostBack)
{

//Fill the Drop down

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are binding drop down on PostBack, inside PageLoad event. Use

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
//do the binding here ...
}
```

and when your page postbacks (after the drop down value has changed, it wont bind again, as the page is not a new load, its now a post back)